# Why would np.shape return a list instead of a tuple?

Tags: numpy

I'm programming a simple neural network. While programming the backpropagation function, I got an index error when coding the partial derivatives of the bias terms for the last layer. This is unsurprising; there are so many indices to keep track of, mistakes are to be expected. So just for debugging, I inserted a print(np.shape) command so I can compare the dimensions of certain things to what they should be according to written plan. But to my frustration, Python seems to ignore the np.shape command and just prints the whole long list instead!

Here is the backpropagation function so far:

```
def neural_network_backward(X,Y,Z,W,b,z,a):
    da=[0 for i in range(len(a))]
    dz=[0 for i in range(len(z))]
    dW=[0 for i in range(len(W))]
    db=[0 for i in range(len(b))]
    da[len(da)-1]=[(-Z[k]/a[len(a)-1][k]*len(Z))+((1-Z[k])/(1-a[len(a)-1][k])*len(Z)) for k in range(len(Z))]
    dz[len(dz)-1]=[[(Z[k]-a[len(a)-1][k])/len(Z) for k in range(len(Z))],[(a[len(a)-1][k]-Z[k])/len(Z) for k in range(len(Z))]]
    dW[len(dW)-1]=np.matmul(dz[len(dz)-1],np.transpose(a[len(a)-2]))
    print(np.shape(dz[len(dz)-1]))
    db[len(db)-1]=[[np.sum([dz[len(dz)-1][i][j] for i in range(np.shape(dz[len(dz)-1])[1])])] for j in range(len(b[len(b)-1]))]
    return da,dz,dW,db
```

- X and Y are the inputs (lists of numbers, length 40000 in this example)
- Z is the class label (list of 0s or 1s, also length 40000)
- W is the weights (list of length the number of layers, each element of the list a matrix of numbers)
- b is biases (list of length the number of layers, each element a column vector of numbers)
- z is a list storing what goes into each layer's nonlinear function
- a is a list storing the output of each layer's nonlinear function

X, Y, Z, W and b are given (or rather generated in my example), while z and a are calculated by the forward propagation function.

As I said, this code hits an index error in the db line. But my question isn't about that; it's about the print line. It returns...

> (array([None, None,
> list([-178817.32020913006, 115656.44251148969, -410256.53703781555, -44727.1419577356, "tens of thousands more numbers"...

**My question is: How can this be an output for np.shape? Shouldn't np.shape return a list of integers, or hit an error trying?**

I don't know if this is needed for my question, but just to make sure, here's my code for the forward propagation function. It's how I get a, which is needed as input into the backward propagation function.

```
def neural_network_forward(X,Y,W,b):
    depth=len(W)
    z=[]
    a=[]
    for i in range(depth):
        weights=np.array(W[i])
        biases=np.array([[b[i][j] for k in range(len(X))] for j in range(len(b[i]))])
        if i==0:
            inputs=np.array([X,Y])
            z.append(np.matmul(weights,inputs)+biases)
        else:
            inputs=a[len(a)-1]
            z.append(np.matmul(weights,inputs)+biases)
        if i<depth-1:
            a.append([[np.amax(z[len(z)-1][j][k],0) for k in range(len(X))] for j in range(len(z[len(z)-1]))])
        else:
            z_final=[[z[len(z)-1][j][k] for k in range(len(X))] for j in range(2)]
            a.append([np.exp(z_final[1][k])/(np.exp(z_final[0][k])+np.exp(z_final[1][k])) for k in range(len(X))])
            loga_final=[z_final[1][k]-logadd([z_final[0][k],z_final[1][k]]) for k in range(len(X))]
    return z,a,loga_final
```

Comment: Unrelated to your question but all these `da[len(da)-1]` are really distracting. Python and almost all Python libraries support indexing from the end. `da[-1]` is strictly equivalent to `da[len(da)-1]` and much more readable

Comment: I think the print is coming from some place else.

Comment: No other print commands (except a simple for loop counter). But strangely enough, closing and reopening Python fixed the problem. This question can be closed; sorry for the inconvenience.