# Inconsistent Python Errors when Coding Neural Network

Tags: python, numpy, neural-network

This is a follow-on to the question I asked yesterday: [Why would np.shape return a list instead of a tuple?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76033943/why-would-np-shape-return-a-list-instead-of-a-tuple)

I'm continuing to run into errors while writing and running my neural network code. But the errors aren't consistent; I get a different error when I rerun the same code. Partly this can be explained by use of random functions, which changes the data with each run. But that can't be the whole story; errors may disappear if I save data with np.save, close Python, open Python, and load it back with np.load.

Sorry for the lengthiness of this question. I can't figure out where the real problems are, so I see little choice but to provide enough code to replicate the problems.

```
def generate_data(n,var0,var1):
    data=[]
    for i in range(n):
        z=np.random.binomial(1,0.5)
        if z==0:
            x,y=np.random.multivariate_normal(mean=[0,0],cov=[[1,var0],[var0,1]])
        elif z==1:
            x,y=np.random.multivariate_normal(mean=[1,1],cov=[[1,var1],[var1,1]])
        data.append([x,y,z])
    return data

def cross_validation(data):
    n=len(data)
    copy=list(data)
    random.shuffle(copy)
    part0=copy[0:int(n/5)]
    part1=copy[int(n/5):int(2*n/5)]
    part2=copy[int(2*n/5):int(3*n/5)]
    part3=copy[int(3*n/5):int(4*n/5)]
    part4=copy[int(4*n/5):n]
    partitioned_copy=[part0,part1,part2,part3,part4]
    folds=[]
    for i in range(5):
        training_set=[]
        for j in range(5):
            if j!=i:
                for point in partitioned_copy[j]:
                    training_set.append(point)
        testing_set=partitioned_copy[i]
        folds.append([training_set,testing_set])
    return folds

# Two functions to add and subtract numbers respectively, when given the logs of the numbers rather than the numbers themselves
def logadd(x):
    n=np.max([int(num) for num in x])
    y=[num-n for num in x]
    ey=np.exp(y)
    return n+np.log(np.sum(ey))

def logsubtract(a,b):
    n=np.max([int(a),int(b)])
    return n+np.log(np.exp(a-n)-np.exp(b-n))

def initialize_network(layer_sizes):
    W=[]
    b=[]
    for i in range(len(layer_sizes)):
        if i==0:
            W.append(np.random.randn(layer_sizes[i],2))
        else:
            W.append(np.random.randn(layer_sizes[i],layer_sizes[i-1]))
        b.append(np.zeros(layer_sizes[i]))
    return W,b

def neural_network_forward(X,Y,W,b):
    depth=len(W)
    z=[]
    a=[]
    for i in range(depth):
        weights=np.array(W[i])
        biases=np.array([[b[i][j] for k in range(len(X))] for j in range(len(b[i]))])
        if i==0:
            inputs=np.array([X,Y])
            z.append(np.matmul(weights,inputs)+biases)
        else:
            inputs=a[len(a)-1]
            z.append(np.matmul(weights,inputs)+biases)
        if i<depth-1:
            a.append([[np.amax(z[len(z)-1][j][k],0) for k in range(len(X))] for j in range(np.shape(z[len(z)-1])[0])])
        else:
            z_final=[[z[len(z)-1][j][k] for k in range(len(X))] for j in range(2)]
            a.append([np.exp(z_final[1][k])/(np.exp(z_final[0][k])+np.exp(z_final[1][k])) for k in range(len(X))])
            loga_final=[z_final[1][k]-logadd([z_final[0][k],z_final[1][k]]) for k in range(len(X))]
    return z,a,loga_final

def neural_network_backward(X,Y,Z,W,b,z,a):
    depth=len(W)
    da=[0 for i in range(len(a))]
    dz=[0 for i in range(len(z))]
    dW=[0 for i in range(len(W))]
    db=[0 for i in range(len(b))]
    da[len(da)-1]=[-Z[k]/(a[len(a)-1][k]*len(Z))+(1-Z[k])/((1-a[len(a)-1][k])*len(Z)) for k in range(len(Z))]
    dz[len(dz)-1]=[[(Z[k]-a[len(a)-1][k])/len(Z) for k in range(len(Z))],[(a[len(a)-1][k]-Z[k])/len(Z) for k in range(len(Z))]]
    dW[len(dW)-1]=np.matmul(dz[len(dz)-1],np.transpose(a[len(a)-2]))
    db[len(db)-1]=[[np.sum([dz[len(dz)-1][i][j] for j in range(np.shape(dz[len(dz)-1])[1])])] for i in range(np.shape(dz[len(dz)-1])[0])]
    for i in reversed(range(depth-1)):
        da[i]=np.matmul(np.transpose(W[i+1]),dz[i+1])
        dz[i]=np.empty([np.shape(z[i])[0],len(X)])
        for j in range(np.shape(z[i])[0]):
            for k in range(len(X)):
                if z[i][j][k]>0:
                    dz[i][j][k]=da[i][j][k]
                elif z[i][j][k]<0:
                    dz[i][j][k]=0
        if i>0:
            dW[i]=np.matmul(dz[i],np.transpose(a[i-1]))
        elif i==0:
            dW[i]=np.matmul(dz[i],np.transpose(np.array([X,Y])))
        db[i]=[[np.sum([dz[i][j][k] for k in range(np.shape(dz[i])[1])])] for j in range(np.shape(dz[i])[0])]
    return da,dz,dW,db

def cost(X,Y,Z,W,b,loga_final):
    total_loss=0
    def loss(loga,z):
        return -(z*loga+(1-z)*logsubtract(0,loga))
    for k in range(len(Z)):
        total_loss+=loss(loga_final[k],Z[k])/len(Z)
    return total_loss

def gradient_descent(X,Y,Z,W_start,b_start,learning_rate):
    cost_history=[]
    forward=neural_network_forward(X,Y,W_start,b_start)
    previous_cost=np.inf
    current_cost=cost(X,Y,Z,W_start,b_start,forward[2])
    cost_history.append(current_cost)
    a=forward[1]
    z=forward[0]
    W=W_start
    b=b_start
    while previous_cost-current_cost>=0.001:
        backward=neural_network_backward(X,Y,Z,W_start,b_start,forward[0],forward[1])
        backward02=learning_rate*backward[0][2]
        break
    return backward02
# There's more to this function, but I inserted a call to this specific component of the backwards propagation output, followed by a break, because an error often occurs here.

def neural_network(folds):
    for i in range(1):
    # Of course it should be range(5) here, but cut it down to 1 for testing.
        training_set=folds[i][0]
        testing_set=folds[i][1]
        X=[training_set[k][0] for k in range(len(training_set))]
        Y=[training_set[k][1] for k in range(len(training_set))]
        Z=[training_set[k][2] for k in range(len(training_set))]
        basic_accuracies.append(correct_predictions/len(testing_set))
        W,b=initialize_network([3,5,2])
    return X,Y,Z,W,b
# There's also much more to this function that has been commented out. I stop it here so I can conveniently store the parameters and variables up to this point

grid_values=[0.1*i for i in range(-9,-8)]
# This range is shrunk down to a single value for testing.
        
progress=0
for var0 in grid_values:
    for var1 in grid_values:
        print(progress)
        data=generate_data(50000,var0,var1)
        X=[data[i][0] for i in range(len(data))]
        Y=[data[i][1] for i in range(len(data))]
        Z=[data[i][2] for i in range(len(data))]
        folds=cross_validation(data)
        X,Y,Z,W,b=neural_network(folds)
        backward02=gradient_descent(X,Y,Z,W,b,0.01)
        progress+=1
```

When I run this code as is, I get one of two errors:

UnboundLocalError: local variable 'backward02' referenced before assignment (referencing the `return backward02` line)

or

TypeError: can't multiply sequence by non-int of type 'float' (referencing the `backward02=learning_rate*backward[0][2]` line)

I don't understand how the first error could occur; the while loop should always be entered once before breaking, which would assign backward02 a value before returning it. As for the second error, deleting the multiplication by learning_rate removes the error. When I then view backward02 in the variable explorer, it shows a list of floats; so I have no idea why it would reject multiplying by a float. However, when I tried np.save-ing backward02, closing Python, reopening Python and np.loading-ing it, then I was able to multiply by 0.01 without an error.

So what's the real reason for these errors?

Comment: There is no guarantee that while loop is entered once before breaking. If condition is initially false, it will never be entered.

Comment: can previous_cost-current_cost be <= 0.00 ? cos if so then you're returning the backward02 without any assignment

Comment: `learning_rate` is a `sequence`, like a string or list,  It should be something like a numpy array.

Comment: Ok, I think I see the problems. For the first error, I assumed previous_cost-current_cost should always be inf because previous_cost is set to inf. But it turns out that current_cost may be inf as well; I'll have to look into why. As for the second error, I thought Python would broadcast basic operations like addition or multiplication across lists; but I guess not. In any case, wrapping backward[0][2] with np.array fixes the problem. Thanks.

Comment: `list` has its own definition of `*` (and `+`).  `numpy` functions often take `list` arguments, doing their own conversion to array.  With operators such a conversion only occurs when the other argument is an array.